# BizTalk Office 365 Mail Adapter is unable to pick specific attachment as body

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

I am trying to reproduce **POP3 Adapter** email retreival with **Office 365 Mail Adapter** to retreive email's attachment and parse its content.

This was done by POP3's settings **Apply MIME Decoding** = True, **Body Part Index** = 2.

There are no equivalent settings for the Office 365 Mail adapter, or am I missing something? As I understand, further development of custom pipeline component needs to be done in order to extract correct body part, and apply as a new message...?